# Varying ship prices?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I noticed while I was traveling around that the same ship can vary in price from station to station. In this specific instance, the [Keelback](https://coriolis.edcd.io/outfit/keelback), which is normally 3.1 million credits (as seen on the referenced site), was for sale in a station/system I had never visisted for [2.6 million](https://snag.gy/aAY01j.jpg).

What accounts for the difference in price I'm observing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some systems sell ships and equipment at discounted prices. For example, all ships are offered for a 15% discount at any system controlled or exploited by Li Yong-Rui.

Here's a list of currently known discounts:

### Discounts on Ships and Outfitting

```
All outfitting & ships
   Location: Li Yong-Rui Controlled and Exploited systems
   Discount: 15%
   Requirements: None

All outfitting and ships
   Location: Founders world (Shinrarta Dezhra) - All stations
   Discount: 10%
   Requirements: Permit gained via Elite rank or backer level

All Ships and limited outfitting
   Location: CD-43 11917 - Attilius Orbital
   Discount: 20% on selected ships, 30% on selected modules
   Requirements: Permit gained via CQC Prestige
```

Details on the latter (Attilius Orbital): https://www.reddit.com/r/EliteCQC/comments/3r6z3d/cd43_11917_attilius_orbital_discounts/

### Discounts on Specific Ships

```
ASP
   Location: Alioth - Irkutsk Station
   Discount: 20%
   Requirements: Alioth Permit

Orca
   Location: Alioth - Irkutsk Station
   Discount: 20%
   Requirements: Alioth Permit

Diamondback Explorer
   Location: Wolf 406 - Hamilton Gateway
   Discount: 20%
   Requirements: None

Eagle
   Location: Sol - Daedalus Station
   Discount: 20%
   Requirements: Sol Permit

Vulture
   Location: Sol - Daedalus Station
   Discount: 10%
   Requirements: Sol Permit

Eagle
   Location: Beta Hydri - Edmondson High
   Discount: 10%
   Requirements: Beta Hydri Permit

Imperial Ships
   Location: Denton Paterus Controlled systems
   Discount: 10%
   Requirements: None
```

### Discounts on Specific Outfitting

```
Weapons
   Location: Zachary Hudson Controlled systems
   Discount: 20%
   Requirements: None

Cargo racks and Hull Reinforcement (Does not apply to Bulkheads)
   Location: Edmund Mahon Controlled systems
   Discount: 20%
   Requirements: None
```

Information was taken from [this thread](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php/155377-Active-Discounts-thread) at the official forums. These discounts (except those related to Powerplay) are subject to change, so this info might change. The forum thread seems to be updated regularly so information there should be pretty accurate.

Comment: Your first list says Attilius Orbital has discounts on "All ships" but then says it's "20% on ***select*** ships" (emphasis mine) - which is it? For the "Specific Ships" list, which Asp is discounted at Irkutsk Station - Explorer, Scout, or both? Also, in what system is Founders World?

Comment: @Iszi Founder's World is a nickname for the Shinrarta Dezhra system, so-called because being a founding member (Kickstarter backer) of the game provides immediate access to this otherwise permit-locked system.

Comment: @Iszi  For the other questions you posed, I cannot answer them because my knowledge comes from the thread linked in the answer and that information is not specifically stated there. The information was copied from the link solely to preserve the knowledge available at the time the question was asked. I am not in a situation in-game to be able to fact check these meticulously, but I can turn this answer into a community wiki if everyone wants to keep this answer completely current..